# Rename default column name in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I have created a dataframe randomly and want to rename the column index.I run the following code for that but it gives me no results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10))
Out[6]:

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

In the above problem I want to change Column index and for that I have applied the following code

```
df.rename(columns={'': 'A'}, inplace=True)
```

It runs but giving no result.

Comment: `df.columns = list('abcdefghij')`

Comment: index is not a column so you can't rename it. what's your exact problem?

Comment: if you mean change the header names, then @dave-cz is right